# Unable to debug my quicksort program

Tags: c, sorting

```
#include <stdio.h>


int Partition (int * A, int p, int r)
{
    printf("PARTITION\n");
    int x=0;
    x=A[r];
    int i=p-1, j=r+1;
    int temp;
    int k=0;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\tLOOP\n");
        do
        {
            j=j-1;
        } while(A[j]>x) ;

        do
        {
            i=i+1;
        } while(A[i]<x);

        if (i<j)
        {
            temp=A[i];
            A[i]=A[j];
            A[j]=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("ARRAY: ");
            for (k=p; k<=r; k++)
                printf ("%d,",A[k]);
            printf ("\nRETURNING : %d \n", j);

            return j;
        }

    }
}
void QuickSort(int * A, int p, int r)
{
    int q;
    if (p<r)
    {
        q = Partition (A,p,r);
        QuickSort(A,p,q);
        QuickSort(A,q+1,r);
    }

}



int main()
{
    int A[9] = {9,2,4,1,7,8,3,5,6};
    int i;
    QuickSort(A,0,8);
    for (i=0;i<=8;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After an hour on GDB, I've narrowed the problem of this program down to this:

My array has indexes from 0-9.
It first gets partitioned as 0-5 and 6-9.
Then the 0-5 part gets partitioned as 0-2 and 3-5
Then the 0-2 part gets partitioned as 0-0 and 1-2
Now the 0-0 part gets skipped because of the `if (p<r)` condition, but the program calls Partition (A,1,2) for the other part. Now here is where the program gets stuck, it keeps on calling Partition (A,1,2) again and again since it keeps returning '2' as the pivot index.

Why is this happening? I can't understand where I've gone wrong in the program logically, I followed the exact pseudocode which is given on various places on the internet.

EDIT: I was able to solve the issue by using `if (i<=j)` instead of `if (i<j)` in `Partition`. It forces `j` to be decremented once more, but that's only because I was fortunate enough to have chosen `do while` instead of `while`. I'm still puzzled why a direct implementation of Quicksort pseudocode didn't work.

Comment: You could compare your implementation with the reference C implementation [at Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#C)

Comment: The exact pseudo-code?  There are a lot of variations on QuickSort with lots of different pseudo-codes; it would be sensible to give the link to the pseudo-code you used.  Besides, if you had followed the exact pseudo-code exactly, your QuickSort would be working (unless you managed to find a broken pseudo-code for QuickSort).  Since it wasn't working, we have to infer that you're a human, not a machine, and you made a mistake in translating the pseudo-code into C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made lot of mistakes in your code.

- `QuickSort(A,p,q);` is `QuickSort(A,p,q-1)`;
- `int i=p-1, j=r+1;` is not necessary.
- Your `partition()` , will need an extra variable to hold the pivot.
- `while(A[i]<x) ;` should be `while(A[i] <= x[piv] && i<r )`;
- In your program , you have missed an algorithm step where the array variable at the pivot , is swapped with your last array variable , without this crucial step , no sorting takes place.

Here's your program , with the corrections made

```
#include <stdio.h>


int Partition (int  *A, int p, int r)
{
    printf("PARTITION\n");
    int i=p, j=r ,piv=p ;
    int temp;

    while(i<j)
    {
        printf("\tLOOP\n");

       while(A[i] <= A[piv] && i<r)
           i++;

       while(A[j]>A[piv]) 
           j--;


            if (i<j)
            {
                temp=A[i];
                A[i]=A[j];
                A[j]=temp;
            }
    }

/*Crucial step that you happen to miss*/
         temp=A[piv];
         A[piv]=A[j];
         A[j]=temp;

return j;
}


void QuickSort(int *A, int p, int r)
{
    int q;
    if (p<r)
    {
        q = Partition (A,p,r);
        QuickSort(A,p,q-1);
        QuickSort(A,q+1,r);
    }
}



int main()
{
    int A[9] = {9,2,4,1,7,8,3,5,6};
    int i;
    QuickSort(A,0,8);
    for (i=0;i<=8;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```